# Spark how to execute one map action on only one work node?

Tags: apache-spark

I am evaluating some database schema dynamically. Since there are a large number of schemas, evaluating them on one single PC is not practical. I want to use Spark to finish this work, by evaluating each one of schemas on one work node. The evaluation procedure will be like this.

(1) create test load for each one of schemas, and store all test loads in Hadoop file system or work nodes' local file system. The test loads are just insert and select statements in .SQL files, but with large size.
(2) read test loads from file system, and give the statements to mysql to execute with JDBC. I will record the time spent at the same time.

We can treat the evaluation procedure as a function the "e", it takes a database schema as input, and output the time consumption of evaluation. We can map the function to the array of schemas, to get a array of evaluated time.

Is there any way to achieve this in Spark? Since I have to make the function run on just one work node, the question would be: is there a way to run each map action on just one work node?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

No easy way of doing it in Spark. And more important, there's no meaning in doing this evaluation in Spark. The thing you need it something like distributed orchestration. You have following choices:

1. Use Spark for this. You can start it on Yarn and specify maximum amount of memory available to Yarn on each of the nodes, it will prevent it from scheduling more than one execution container per node. Or you can make a hack like locking some semaphore or just a file on the filesystem to prevent all the other containers from execution except by the first one. But in either scenario, using Spark for this is not the best option
2. Write custom code for this. It is simple - write shell/python/perl script to execute the code you need for specific schema. Accept schema name as a parameter. In the main application get the number of machines and schedule remote executions by creating ssh session to remote machine and waiting for it to complete
3. Write a bit more complicated code. In ACID DBMS, create a table with the list of schemas you want to evaluate. Create a worker that will connect to the database, get one of the schemas from this file and mark it for execution (update this metadata table), then execute you testing logic and store test results into the database

In my opinion both options 2 and 3 are easier to implement and easier to control their results. But if in fact you need to run this evaluation daily and this is some kind of routing task for your system, I would code it as a combination of approach 1 with spark for execution and approach 3 with centralized metadata in ACID DBMS

Comment: Thank you so much! After thinking it for a while, I also think it's not a classical map-reduce job in some sense. The main problem I have is that evaluating these schemas with one single PC will take as long as 15 days, it's kind of unacceptable. I need a way to reduce the evaluation time. I think maybe 2 is the simplest way. Thank you!